# How to configure ASP.NET MVC to use ADFS oAuth as Authorization Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, adfs

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC application (not ASP.NET vNext or ASP.NET MVC Core). I have Active Directory Server with ADFS configured. I registered my application as application group under oAuth application.

In the end I received ClietnId & Secret Key.

What I want to achieve is - I want to use `OWIN middleware` for configuring `oAuthServer` that points to `ADFS oAuthServer` rather than using custom code.

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I'm not to sure which part you are having trouble with but in the startup of your application you should initialize WsFederationAuthenticationOptions.

Comment: @the_lotus - I don't want to use WsFederationAuthenticationOptions rather I want to use oAuthAuthorizationServer.

My understanding is that WsFederation and oAuth are different things.